# Confusing point in List documentation

Tags: java, list, collections, arraylist, linked-list

I am not clear on a point in the documentation of [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

It says:

> i) Note that these operations may execute in time proportional to the
>   index value for some implementations (the LinkedList class, for
>   example).
>   ii) Thus, iterating over the elements in a list is typically
>   preferable to indexing through it if the caller does not know the
>   implementation.

*Note that I put the (i) and (ii) in the quote.*

Point (i) is pretty obvious due to the way we access a linked list vs the random access of an array.

I can not understand point (ii) though.
What do we gain by prefering an iterator if we don't know the implementation?
I mean if the implementation is a `LinkedList` is there any difference in the performance than accessing via the index?
I imagine not, since the `Iterator` would be manipulating a `LinkedList` anyway.
So there would be no difference.

So what is the meaning of the recommendation of (ii) in the doc?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The iterator of a linked list can just have a pointer to the next node in the list, and go to the next node each time `next()` is called. It doesn't start from the beginning every time. Whereas if you use an index and call `get(i)`, the linked list has to iterate from the beginning until the ith element at each iteration.

What you missed is that the iterator implementation of an ArrayList and the one of a LinkedList are completely different.

Answer (score 4):

No, if the implementation is a `LinkedList` then an iterator will be much more efficient - O(n) for iterating over the whole list instead of O(N<sup>2</sup>). As the iterator is provided *by* the list, it has access to the internal data structures. It can just keep a reference to "the current node" making it a constant time operation to get to the next one: just follow the link!

(If you're still confused, I suggest you just look at the implementation - that's likely to make it clearer.)

Comment: @ John Skeet:So the idea is that (for example in a for loop) if I do `list.get(i)` the `get` method would have to traverse all the prior elements to reach node `i` while using the iterator the `get(i)` would be just following the `next` pointer since the iterator is in the node of the previous loop?Have I got the concept?

Comment: @user384706: Yes, that's exactly it.